# error: could not open file "/root/Data.csv" for reading: Permission denied

Tags: node.js, postgresql, csv

I'm trying  to run copy command using Node.js. I'm getting permission denied error but I have already given permission to the file.

I'm using PostgreSQL database.

If I run command

```
\COPY aws_scheduler from '/root/Data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER`
```

its working properly with data reflected in database but using Node.js code its giving error.

Here's my  code

```
config.query("COPY aws_scheduler from '/root/Data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;", function (err, result) {
if (!err) {
console.log(result);
}
else {
console.log('Error while performing Query.', err);
}
});
```

[image: screenshot of error]

I attached screenshot of error when running node js file.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/root` is an important folder. Move your csv file to `/tmp` folder and try again. Possibly your problem will solved.

Difference between `Copy` and `\Copy` described in [Postgresql documnet](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html)

> Do not confuse COPY with the psql instruction \copy. \copy invokes COPY FROM STDIN or COPY TO STDOUT, and then fetches/stores the data in a file accessible to the psql client. Thus, file accessibility and access rights depend on the client rather than the server when \copy is used.

Comment: Using `/tmp` is an easy work-around when doing one-off loads or dumps, instead of playing with permissions for users (database or system) or directories, that may not be desirable to keep.